# Activating/Deactivating virtual Env both returns the expression [sys.prefix != sys.base_prefix] as False

Tags: python, python-venv

I just created a simple virtual environment, installed a library in it and when imported, it throws the classic module not found error. When checked for the`sys.prefix != sys.base_prefix` it is returning `False` which means virtual environment is not getting activated possibly but if you look at the terminal there is parenthesis enclosing the env `(langconv)`

Can somebody please point out what could possibly the error here.

**CODE:**

```
import sys
import pandas

if sys.prefix != sys.base_prefix:
    print("yes, my virtual environment is up and running... :)")
else:
    print("No, my virtual environment is not up and running... :(")
    print("    ",sys.prefix)
    print("    ",sys.base_prefix)
```

**IMAGE:**

[image: pyencnfg]

[image]

Comment: Please post the code and error as a text, not a screenshoot.

Comment: Pip freeze your current environment

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon It seems something to do with the code Runner. I tried to tinker it's settings but to no avail. So just removed it.